# La copia del proyecto Django muestra las plantillas del antiguo proyecto

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Copié y pegué [un proyecto desarollado con Django](https://github.com/antoinecomp/todowoo) para modificarlo. Sin embargo, después de modificar un poco una de las plantillas (el home.html), no aparece ninguna modificación. ¿Es porque este proyecto no es original? ¿Tengo que recrearlo desde el principio?

Por ejemplo, cambié el nombre de la plantilla "home.html" por "homes.html". Entonces la primera no debe ser llamada y todo eso debe resultar en un error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero como pueden verlo no hay nignun error y el home.html continúa siendo llamado

Answer (score 0):

Después de hacer ese cambio recargaste el servidor o detecto los cambios y se recargo automáticamente? A veces sucede eso, que no detecta los cambios y tienes que reiniciar el servidor local de manera manual. Si se recargo bien, entonces te tendria que dar el error TemplateDoesNotExist ya que no existe el home.html y te dirá en que directorios intento buscar el template.

Si modificas los templates de tus otras urls ¿si detecta los cambios de tus templates?.

También te recomiendo revisar la configuración TEMPLATES del settings para ver que este correcta y este tomando los directorios correctos, puedes ver un poco mas sobre esto aquí: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/templates/#support-for-template-engines